# Como puedo hacer yo para mostrar el nombre y no el id en un select?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Como puedo hacer yo para mostrar el nombre y no el id en un select? Estoy teniendo un problema al mostrar el nombre de un holding en un select. Yo tengo una tabla que se llama holdings con un listado de nombres:

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
```

Despues mi tabla customers contiene el id de la tabla holdings:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('holding_id');
$table->foreign('holding_id')->references('id')->on('holdings');
```

Y mi tabla contacto contiene un campo que es el id de la tabla customers:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

Y mi select de mi vista es el siguiente

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="customer_id">Cuenta</label>
   <select name="customer_id" id="" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="">Seleccione la cuenta del contacto</option>
      @foreach ($customers as $key => $customer)
      <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->holding_id}}</option>               
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

Pero las opciones del select son solo el id. Como puedo hacer para poder mostrar el nombre del holding asociado a las otras tablas y no el id?

Comment: Utiliza relaciones en los modelos para identificar si es de muchos a muchos, muchos a uno, o uno a uno, con esto puedes obtener el registro de cada holding

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar tus modelos ,crea dos modelos uno **Holding** y otro **Customer**
en tu modelo Customer debes añadir la relación

```
 public function holding()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Holding::class,'holding_id');
 }
```

y a si ya puedes acceder al holding de cada customer

```
 <select name="customer_id" id="" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione la cuenta del contacto</option>
    @foreach ($customers as $key => $customer)
       <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->holding->name}}</option>                       
    @endforeach
 </select>
```